# Do I need to care about constants in Expectation Propagation

Tags: inference, approximation, variational-bayes

I am trying to approximate a certain factor in my graph. 
[image]

Following Tom Minka's tutorial what I have to do is as follows:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^3 q_{w_i}(\pi_2)\approx \int p(\pi_2|w_1)q_{\pi_1}(w_1)\prod_{i=1}^3 q_{D_i}(w_1)\, dw_1\,\, q_{w_2}(\pi_2)q_{w_3}(\pi_2)
$$
where $q_x(y)$ is the message that $y$ receives from $x$, $p(\pi_2|w_1)\propto \pi_2 (1-\pi_2)^{{w_1}^2}$ and the messages $q_{w_i}(\pi_2)$ are all also beta distributed and finally, $q_x(w_1)$ are all gaussians.

My question is with the right hand side of the approximation can I do the following:

$$
RHS \propto \int \pi(1-\pi)^{{w_1}^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(w_1-\mu)^2\right)\times C_1\, dw_1\,\, C_2 \pi^{\alpha_0-1}(1-\pi)^{\beta_0-1}
$$
where I've let $\pi\equiv \pi_2$, $C_1,C_2$ are constants that do not depend on $\pi$ and $\alpha_0, \beta_0$ is obtained by combining the messages from $q_{w_2}, q_{w_3}$. Similarly I've combined the Gaussians, thus giving the exponential term.

So basically I end up with:
$$
RHS \propto \pi^{\alpha_0}(1-\pi)^{\beta_0-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}-2\ln(1-\pi)\right)
$$

**Can I simply moment match this with a Beta distribution** to get the approximation, in this case the moments being $E(\ln \pi), E(\ln (1-\pi))$ (my interpretation of the proj operation) and divide by the LHS messages or is there more to do.

Finally trying to find these messages for each factor seems tedious and no closed form for moments as above. **Are there any tips or comments on making inference on this easier/ faster**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply moment match this with a Beta distribution and divide.  The moments that you mention can be computed in closed form.